# Why Azure takes so long to setup a Load Balancer?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have set up an application gateway in almost five different regions in Azure and every time Azure take around 15-20 mins to complete the setup.

Whereas AWS will do it in a couple of minutes, why Azure requires such a long time?

Answer (score 5):

You should try using Application Gateway V2, its a lot faster to create. updates are almost instantaneous (well, at least compared to V1). But I believe V1 is using windows VM's underneath, so it creates a set of vms for you, then it configures them. Each update would be a "sliding window" update, with 1 vm being recreated at a time.

As far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Application Gateway is a layer 7 load balancer which, as far as I understand, is a Windows VM (or collection of Windows VMs, depending on selected size) under the covers, which take some time to come up and be configured. In my experience, this time is usually around 15-30 minutes, depending on region and local time of day, capacity, etc.

Azure Load balancers on the other hand are layer 4 load balancers, which typically take in the order of 1-2 minutes to come up.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes talking about the load balancer if you say it normally takes less than a minute to get deployed. But coming onto the Application gateway yeah it takes 15-20 minutes every time the reason being:

1. **Configuration Settings:** Microsoft has the set of the vacant load balancers ready at their backend and when they receive a request to deploy a particular load balancer in any region, they just assign it an IP as requested by the user and it gets deployed within a minute. But coming onto the Application gateway, azure need to start deploying the load balancer [App Gateway in this case] from the scratch, need to attach it to the VNET so deployed and making it ready for the backend pools IP Address configuration and all, which basically take time about [15-20 minutes]. Now, Azure has brought up the V2 of the Application Gateway, a lot faster to create usually 5 minutes. And also talking about updates they are also really quick and instantaneous.
2. **Subscriptions:** Secondly, the reason that it takes time is subscription. Suppose, you have the MSDN, free subscription in your Azure account. And another individual sitting at any different place is using the enterprise applications subscription [basically a pay as you go] in his azure account. Now, both of you raise a request to deploy an Application gateway in the same region at the same time then, Microsoft will give the person request with the enterprise subscription the higher priority than your free subscription request. Which is another reason that it results in a delay. As I am using the enterprise edition so it takes 2 minutes for a VM to deploy which gets deployed in 5-6 minutes if using the free subscription!

Thanks!